# Derived class in multiple inheritance behaves like an aggregate

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, c++17

I could get the following code (also found in cppreference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to compile (https://wandbox.org/permlink/stCFKi0VQlF49Bxr)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Types>
struct Overload : public Types... {
    using Types::operator()...;
};
template <typename... Types>
auto make_overload(Types&&... instances) {
    return Overload<std::decay_t<Types>...>{std::forward<Types>(instances)...};
}

int main() {
    auto overloaded = make_overload([](int) {}, [](double) {});
    static_cast<void>(overloaded);
}
```

How does the code above compile in C++17?  It does not compile in C++14.  What is happening behind the scenes?  Also why does the variadic `using` declaration not work in C++14?  Which new feature is this?

Comment: Interesting.  I thought this would work in C++14 as well, somehow the rules for expansion changed in C++17?

Comment: you can simplify your example: in C++17 your example compile also without `using`, `std::decay_t` and `std::forward`

Comment: This [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) says that public bases no longer prevent classes from being aggregates since C++17. This [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) says that variadic `using`s were added in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [parameter_pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack),

Introduced in C++17

> The following is the list of all allowed contexts: [...]
>
> Using-declarations
> In using declaration, ellipsis may appear in the list of declarators, this is useful when deriving from a parameter pack:

```
template <typename... bases>
struct X : bases... {
    using bases::g...;
};
X<B, D> x; // OK: B::g and D::g introduced
```